# Android Studio Fragments Logout function with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to do a function "Logout" with Firebase API, in class that extends Fragments, its my class:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // i've done a function : 
    public void LogOut(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Usuario.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'Intent' and finish()

Answer (score 0):

```
 btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Usuario.this, use getActivity().
The method getActivity() is normally used in fragments to get the context of the activity in which they are inserted or inflated.

Answer (score 0):

```
// call requestIdToken as follows
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
val mGoogleSignInClient = activity?.let { 
    GoogleSignIn.getClient(it, gso) 
}

logOutButton.setOnClickListener {
    mGoogleSignInClient?.signOut()?.addOnCompleteListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Logging Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
        startActivity(intent) 
        activity?.finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34967772)